# Lost .tex file, how to restore it? Using synctex?

Tags: forward-inverse-search

something really stupid happened to me. I was running a matlab code, my computer crashed as it completey ran out of memory, i had to restart it.

Unfortunately, at the same time a had a .tex file open. I wanted to save it, but it could not be saved as there was no memory (i use a 128GB SSD, 90% full, the file produced by matlab seems to have swollen to something like 10GB).

Anyway, when I turned on the computer again, the .tex file and the .pdf file were gone... the .log and .aux file are empty. For some reason I still have a .synctex file that seems to contain information associated with the lost file.

Is it possible to use the .synctex file to recapture the .tex file?

Any help or info is highly appreciated
Thanks

PS: I am using TexShop

Comment: `synctex` is used only to keep info about the line numbers of your file so you can do inverse search. No way to restore the content of `tex` file from `synctex`.

Comment: Does TeXShop have a temporary folder (I don't know)? If so you could look in an "autosave" folder. Otherwise you are pretty lost. You can do binary search if you think TeXShop keeps it in a tmp-folder. Otherwise I would suspect you have lost your data. :(

Comment: alright, thank you. then i guess i lost it...

Comment: there might also be a hidden backup file with the ending `.swp`. But i'm not sure

Comment: What about `.bak` file? Not sure about texshop and Mac.

Comment: Look in the directory the `.tex` file was in using `ls -al` to see hidden files. You are looking for one with the same name as the lost file but it may have a different ending and/or a dot in front of it. I seem to remember TeXShop using a `~` somewhere. TeXShop can keep backups. I can't remember if this is default.

Comment: File recovery is off-topic, sorry